# How can I set an EditText in a List in a different class?

Tags: android, eclipse

Basically what I want is: when a person answers "no" with a click on a button (no) I want the empty text view to change to "Why?" and then they can enter the reason in the edittext box. then the final class could list all the issues. android.

```
 package com.toc.maintenance;

 import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
 import java.util.Calendar;

 import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.content.Intent;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.widget.Button;
 import android.widget.TextView;

 public class Safety extends Activity {
Button yes, No, NA, done;

TextView display;

@SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat")
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.setContentView(R.layout.safety);
    No = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bNo);
    yes = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bYes);
    display = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(
            "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    String starttime = dateFormat.format(cal.getTime());

    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Report.class);
    i.putExtra("starttime", starttime);

    yes.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent Safety1 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    Safety1.class);
            startActivity(Safety1);

        }

    });
    NA = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bNA);

    NA.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent Safety1 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    Safety1.class);
            startActivity(Safety1);

        }
    });

    No.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            display.setText("Why?");
        }

    });
    done.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

 //here (at done button)is where I want to capture the editText for the final class 
 //"Report". I have an editBox with "@+id/explain" tag.  
 //But I am going to keep on adding text throughout the app. 
 //I've tried a setText, super, etc. But I just can't get it right. Thanks in advance.
        }

    });

}
```

}

Comment: Ended up using buttons with yes or no and then using .setText when the button was pressed. Became so much easier.

Answer (score 0):

if you meant activity by class then,
You can use `EditTextInstance.getText()` and then you can pass this returned string to other activity(through `intent.putExtra()` ) or class 'using constructor'.

Answer (score 0):

Use putExtra() to send string either "WHY?" or something. Retrieve it using getString();